# SFML 2.1 program compiles but fails to run

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm using SFML 2.1 (SJLJ) for Windows / GCC (32bit)  and am building the project in CodeBlocks 10.05.

I'm trying to run the following code and it crashes. It builds smoothly however.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Many may recognize that this is taken directly from the [SFML 2.1 tutorial site](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) so I doubt there is anything wrong with the code. I've followed all instructions carefully but I have no clue what's causing it.

Some screenshots showing the build options and the actual error output are provided below:

[image: include Path]

[image: lib Path]

[image: Linker Settings - Debug]

[image: Linker Settings - Release]

[image: DLLs are present]

[image: Error Code]

---

Comment: Do not add "solved" to the title of the question. You already indicated that it was solved by accepting an answer (the green checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no idea what was wrong specifically but **upgrading to CodeBlocks 13.12 fixed the issue** for me. It compiles perfectly now!